# How to manage multiple elements in a mouseenter function in Mootools?

Tags: javascript, mootools

**Hi!** I really try to find a topic related to my issue here, but I had  no luck...

Some simple code: I have two divs, placed in the same position -

```
<div id="fader1" style="display:inline-block;position:absolute;background-image:url(images/fader1.png);opacity:1;width:296px;height:435px;margin:-215px 50px -20px"></div>
<div id="fader2" style="display:inline-block;position:absolute;background-image:url(images/fader2.png);opacity:0;width:296px;height:425px;margin:-215px 50px -20px"></div>
```

**The idea is** when the mouse passes over the div "fader1", the opacity changes to 0, and the opacity of fader2 changes to 1. And turn back like the beginning if I put the cursor out of the div.

I've tried to achieve this with mootools but I'm now in a dead-end.

Mootools Demos have the example of Fx.Morph like this:

```
$('myElement').set('opacity', 0.5).addEvents({
    mouseenter: function(){
        // This morphes the opacity and backgroundColor
        this.morph({
            'opacity': 0.6,
            'background-color': '#E79D35'
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        // Morphes back to the original style
        this.morph({
            opacity: 0.5,
            backgroundColor: color
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see, I can only manage ONE element (this.morph). I try to put other element like: "('fader1').morph" with no results... But I think that I'm doing it wrong.

I really appreciate any help you can give me to achieve this in mootools. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

you should read the manual and not copy/paste from examples.

```
$('myElement').set('opacity', 0.5).addEvents({
    mouseenter: function(){
        // This morphes the opacity and backgroundColor
        this.morph({
            'opacity': 0.6,
            'background-color': '#E79D35'
        });
    }
});
```

in the above function, the scope `this` refers to myElement. if you need to reference a different element, then simply do so.

```
(function(){
var other = $('myOtherElement').set('moprh', {
    link: 'cancel'
}); // save a reference and set link to cancel existing morphing

$('myElement').set('opacity', 0.5).addEvents({
    mouseenter: function(){
        // This morphes the opacity and backgroundColor
        other.morph({
            'opacity': 0.6,
            'background-color': '#E79D35'
        });
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        // Morphes back to the original style
        other.morph({
            opacity: 0.5,
            backgroundColor: color
        });
    }
});
}());
```

read up on what $ (documentid) returns (an element), saving an element into a variable and referencing it later - this is standard javascript.